# Check on input Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, input, types

```
Fahr = input("Insert temperature in Fahrenheit: " ) 

while type(Fahr) != float or type(Fahr) != int:

    Fahr = input("Error: Insert temperature in Fahrenheit: " )

Celcius = ((Fahr) - 32) * 5/9


print("Your imput: " + Fahr + " Fahrenheit" ) 

print("This is equal to: " + Celcius + " Celcius" )
```

I need to be sure that the user only inserts INT's or floats. 
When i execute this code, it goes automatically go in the while loop even when i insert an INT or float. 
Whats wrong with this code and how should it be?

Comment: `Fahr` will always be a string (`str`), that's what `input()` returns.

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float-in-python

Comment: Or this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566260/inputing-floats-integers-or-equations-in-raw-input-to-define-a-variable

Comment: I believe the solution is to use the `and` operator instead of the `or` operator. A number can't be both an integer and a float at the same time.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3?  `input()` has different functionality between the two, I was assuming python 3.

Comment: @cdarke, this is Python 3. I tested with Python 2, so maybe I was wrong. i updated my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with the following code:

```
def inp():
    try:
        Fahr = float(raw_input("Insert temperature in Fahrenheit: " ))
        return Fahr
    except Exception as e:
        return e

Fahr = inp()
while True:
    if 'could not convert' in str(Fahr):
        Fahr = inp()
    else:
        break

Celcius = ((Fahr) - 32) * 5/float(9)

print("Your input: " + str(Fahr) + " Fahrenheit" ) 
print("This is equal to: " + str(Celcius) + " Celcius" )
```

The following is the output:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Insert temperature in Fahrenheit: hello
Insert temperature in Fahrenheit: !@
Insert temperature in Fahrenheit: ()()((
Insert temperature in Fahrenheit: 10.5
Your input: 10.5 Fahrenheit
This is equal to: -11.9444444444 Celcius
```

Comment: It "will work fine" unless the user doesn't enter a number, and the OP said that they "need to be sure that the user only inserts INT's or floats," which this doesn't check for.

Comment: I have to print an error and let the user insert a new value, if he inserts a string. Sorry i am new to this site and its my first question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have edited the code. Kindly check.

Comment: Hey Jeril, i tried this. Yes it works, but only for 1 time. So if i insert 2 times a string. The program crashes!

Comment: I have put a modified code, could you check?

Comment: Amazing friend this worked perfectly! Thank u very much :)

Comment: Welcome friend...

Answer (score -1):

`input()` function always return a string.
Convert to `int` or `float` first.

Comment: Fahr = int(input("Insert temperature in Fahrenheit: " )) . I did this now but when i type a string it gives me: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'df'

Comment: That is normal. You can catch this exception and retry the input in that case

Comment: This answer doesn't include anything to ensure that the user enters a number, which the OP requires.